# can I output 1080p onto an external monitor

Tags: display, resolution, external-display

I have an hp envy 14 and It has a native resolution of 1600 * 900. I am trying to buy a monitor which its native resolution is 1080p. can my laptop output 1080p to the external monitor?

Answer (score 1):

found this on yahoo answers:

yes you can...in catalyst control center dont use clone desktop use extend...and set the lcd tv to primary display then set the resolution to 1900x1080 (1080p)

Answer (score 0):

My Macbook has a resolution of 1280x800 and my external monitor is 1900x1080... the answer is of course you can! The resolution a screen offers is not so relevant to the system (at least not in the way you are assuming)